# How can you remove hover from navbar-brand with logo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Double navbar-brand to get both text and logo seems to work perfectly. However, is it easy to remove the hover-hilite for the text brand? My links and drop downs do stuff, but I do not want functionality for clicking on the brand title. The hover is misleading.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top role=navigation">
    <div id="navbar-container" class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- is it possible to turn off the hover/highlight for the text brand? -->
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Codeshelf</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="favicon.gif" width="24" height="24"></a>
        </div>
    <!-- links, dropdowns -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can disable the text brand hover by adding the following CSS and making sure it comes after the core bootstrap CSS file.

```css
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #999999;
}
```

That should do the trick! here is a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xBc5a/)

Comment: Thanks. That does have an effect. On the inverted navbar, it makes the text brand fully disappear on hover (because it goes transparent to pick up the inverted background). Not quite what I want. I would like hover over the text brand to have no hover effect at all.

Comment: @JonR I updated the answer to match the default text color of the text on hover and added a JSFIDDLE.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of Amir5000 has not worked for me.

You can also fix this with this:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="background-color: transparent !important;">Codeshelf</a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="background-color: transparent !important;"><img src="favicon.gif" width="24" height="24"></a>
```

Set a manual inline CSS fix with `!important` to overwrite any other CSS files that modify this setting.

Comment: Thank you Nathan for the English fixes. It's not my primary language ;)